# Odoo ages receivable payable report problem

Tags: odoo, odoo-12

My odoo database migrated from 15 to 16 recently. As the 16 version of aged receivable and payable doesn't seem to be found, the version 15 is used instead. However, this error pop up after it has been running for a while. Is this some runtime error or data error and where can this be changed. Thanks.

File "/home/odoo/src/enterprise/16.0/account_reports/models/account_aged_partner_balance.py", line 366, in _custom_options_initializer
options['account_type'] = [account_type for account_type in options['account_type'] if account_type['id'] not in ('trade_payable', 'non_trade_payable')]
KeyError: 'account_type'

The above server error caused the following client error:
null

Comment: How do you know it's your 15.0 version that run?

Answer (score 0):

This issue was fixed in the (private) Odoo's enterprise repository with [this commit](https://github.com/odoo/enterprise/commit/bc3f549b2e3990d9fa0d6e686fc73a67face4572)

Edit: Also, updating the module `account_report` should also solves the issue.